# Making DDE calls from Java

Tags: java, winapi, native, dde

Wondering if anyone has experience and/or sample code for making DDE calls from Java.  I've done DDE using win32 calls from the stddde library (DdeInitialize, DdeClientTransaction), and could write a JNI wrapper for this, but I was thinking that it might be nice to do it from [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)

I also have some concerns about the fact that DDE calls need to occur from a thread with message pump, and I'm not entirely certain of how to force that in Java.

The calls we'll be doing are pretty simple (equivalent to VBA's DDInitiate, DDEExcecute and DDETerminate functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNA now has a DDE implementation in its contrib repository (the compiled classes are available in the jna-platform artifact):

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/DdemlUtil.java

The unit tests contain many usage examples:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/test/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/DdemlUtilTest.java

Answer (score 5):

http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/

Comment: The client implementation of JDDE is good, but as of version 2.0.4 the server implementation is a bit limited: client disconnections aren't notified, so it's impossible to free the resources allocated to a DDE conversation.

Comment: Link seems dead, but there are some downloads here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jdde/downloads

Answer (score 1):

A decade ago I used [Neva Object Technology](http://nevaobject.com/)'s little DDE wrapper. Works, if you like that sort of thing. But IIRC, you should read the FAQ (although the things it does probably aren't so surprising if you have used DDE before).

Comment: Thanks for the tip-off - I suspect this is the closest that I'm going to get to an off-the-shelf solution. I'll probably wind up adapting a C library we have via JNI.

Comment: NevaObject DDE works very well but the library is available for 32 bits only. The site seems to be dead :(